# Add and use settings

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load settings when the React app starts:

```
fetch(`${window.location.origin}/settings`)
    .then(z => z.json())
    .then((settings) => {
        ReactDOM.render(<App settings={settings} />, document.getElementById('root'));
    });
```

What do I need to do to `App` to:

- pass in the settings; and
- use the settings from anywhere in the application?

In Angular it would be an injectable service with an initializer.

Comment: You need to switch to Angular

Comment: I do; but it's an established app so that ship has sailed. React seems like a complete muddle with code and markup and style all jumbled up -- absolutely don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches to do this, but probably the most practical is to actually have an `AppContainer` component which does the fetch on load:

```
const AppContainer = () => {
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${window.location.origin}/settings`)
            .then(z => z.json())
            .then(s => setSettings(s))
    }, [])

    if (settings === null) return <h1>Loading... </h1>
    return <App settings={settings} />
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The following happens here:

1. `AppContainer` renders in the `root` div.
2. `useEffect` runs and fetches the data
3. `if (settings === null) return <h1>Loading... </h1>` is rendered until `fetch` finishes.
4. `fetch` finishes and sets the state
5. `<App settings={settings} />` renders

Now then, if you'd like to use the settings from anywhere in the application, i'd suggest using a `context` or `redux`.

Here is an example using context API:

```
const SettingsContext = createContext()

const SettingsProvider:React.FC<{ children:JSX.Element }> = ({ children }) => {
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState<null | "Here put whatever the type of the settings you get from your API is. I.E. Array<{name: string, id: number}>">([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${window.location.origin}/settings`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setSettings(data))
    }, []);

    return (
        <SettingsContext.Provider value={settings}>
            {children}
        </SettingsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

This creates the context and does the data fetching when the context is initialized.

```
const App = () => {
   return (
        <SettingsProvider>
            <Fragment> {/* Fragment is for making sure that SettingsProvider has only one child. */}
                <SomeRandomComponent />
            </Fragment>
        </SettingsProvider>
    )
}
```

Here you wrap the children of `App` with the `provider` of the context you created before. This ensures that all children of `SettingsProvider` will have access to the `SettingsContext` recursively.

```
const SomeRandomComponent = () => {
   const settings = useContext(SettingsContext)

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Do stuff with settings */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Finally this component describes how you access the `context`. Note that `SomeRandomComponent` is a child of `SettingsProvider` (see in `App`). This is a must in order to be able to use the context.

Comment: Ta :) I'll give it a go... Really helpful to show an example and use the right names for things because this tells me what to search for.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough Consider approving the answer if it helped you answer your question.

Comment: Can't get it to work. Had to prepend `export` to `const SettingsProvider =` but it doesn't compile because `'React' must be in scope when using JSX`. The `App` already has a lot of things inside it so I don't know where to add `<SettingsProvider>` and even so it's unclear how that will make `App` have a `settings` property to pass in.

Comment: The scope issue is resolved by importing `React` in your `JS/JSX/TSX` file: `import React, { Component }  from 'react';`
As for where the `SettingsProvider` might go, you can also wrap `App` with `SettingsProvider` i.e. `<SettingsProvider> <App /> <SettingsProvider/>` making sure all of App and its childrend will have access to the context.

Comment: `createContext` requires a parameter, and two errors in the `SettingsContext`: `children` implicitly has an 'any' type` and `Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'null'`.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: @RichardBarraclough I just edited the code to make it typescript compatible. When you are using TypeScript, React will not understand that `children` is JSX unless you explicitly specify that. Also, the type error I suspect is caused whenever you are trying to set the settings to your state because it is initially declared as null and then you are trying to change its state to another type. You need to declare the type of the response you are getting from your API as an interface and set the state type to `<null | CustomType>`

Comment: Should that me `<null | Type>` or `<null | Type>`  or `<null | Type>` ? I've seen all three being used and haven't been able to determine any sort of consesnus.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you get back from the `settings API`? It would be much easier to post a solution that way. You could also declare the state as <any> and that would solve your problem but is potential cause of type errors down the line.